# Angular 2 Observable returning array out of order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular 2 project with a method that subscribes to an observable. The observable gets a sorted list of objects from the server and returns it for viewing on the page. However, the array is losing it's order for some reason.

Here is the snippet from the service that is sending the request to the server:

template.service.ts

```
export class TemplateService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getTemplates(): Observable<any> {
      let url = `controller/GetTemplateList`
      return this.http.get(url)
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body;
  }
}
```

And here is the component that is subscribing to the observable:

templates.component.ts

```
export class TemplatesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private templateService: TemplateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.templateService.getTemplates().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)     
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
  }
}
```

The server is returning:

```
{"success":true,"list":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]}
```

But when I do that console.log on the subscription, it looks like this:

```
list:(12) ["G", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
success:true
```

It works properly when I tried an array of 3 elements, but with that full list it returned out of order. Why would it be scrambling the order of the array on the subscribe?

Also, if I remove the two lines from the getTemplates() method so it looks like this:

```
getTemplates(): Observable<any> {
  let url = `controller/GetTemplateList`
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

it returns in the correct order like so:

```
_body:
  "{"success":true,
  "list: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]}"
```

Comment: How do you know that the server is returning the list in the correct order? Have you actually looked at the network response?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the raw response string in the console and it is returning in the correct order.

Comment: I do not recommend you to focus on `templateList.sort` issue at all. The source of the problem is somewhere else and it's better to address it instead of "repairing" the data after it's already messed up. I agree with @Duncan, there is no visible reason for the `.subscribe(...)` to show a differently ordered result sets compared to what the server returns. Could you open the browser console and copy _the very exact_ JSON response you are getting on this API call? Because what you show under `The server is returning:` section is not a valid JSON:`=` characted in `success = true` is not allowed

Comment: This is what would be helpful: https://ibb.co/cjbyAb

Comment: your final example works because you are sorting the array!  Anyway I agree with @IgorSoloydenko, you need to show us the actual raw response data from the server.  What you have showed in the question is not actually JSON and so isn't the true server response data.

Comment: I updated the question with the raw JSON values